File exists exception message
I've only recently gotten into Nim and wanted to write a small script that would recursively walk through a directory, copy the files to a different location and then rename them (the files are automatically generated into separate subdirectories and they're all named in the same fashion, hence why I want to rename them to a more sane format).
To just test if copying works, I wrote down this bit
import std/os
discard existsOrCreateDir(getCurrentDir() & "/data/")

try:
     copyFileWithPermissions("source/cr00000.0_00000.csv", getCurrentDir() & "/data/"
        options = {cfSymlinkIgnore}, ignorePermissionErrors = true)
except CatchableError:
    echo getCurrentExceptionMsg()

and I'm getting the following message
File exists
Additional info: /home/tomasp/Dokumenty/Programs/Nim/data/

It's probably something trivial and I might have missed something while looking at the documentation but I'd appreciate any tips from more veteran users. Feel free to also correct the code if needed, thank you lots.

Copying a file while renaming it:
import std/[os, paths]

let src = Path("/home/chris/tmp/testsndio.c")
let destDir = paths.getCurrentDir() / Path("data")
let srcPath = paths.splitFile(src)
discard existsOrCreateDir(destDir.string)
copyFileWithPermissions(src.string, string(destDir / srcPath.name) & "-renamed" & srcPath.ext)

Converting a string to a paths.Path object allows to

Split it into its dir, base name and file extension component with paths.splitFile.
Concatenate path components with the / operator and thus build the destination path (in the example I added "-renamed" between the base name and the extension).

existsOrCreateDir, copyFileWithPermissions and the & operator expect string arguments resp. operands, though, so the Path objects need to be converted back.

Never mind, I accidentally switched the source with the destination. Using
copyFileToDir("source/cr00000.0_00000.csv", getCurrentDir() & "/data/",
        options = {cfSymlinkAsIs})

did the job just fine in the end. My bad.

It looks like you didn't switch source and destination, but changed copyFileWithPermissions to copyFileToDir.

I had it wrong at first, as you can see in the edit history of this post, before I changed it to this version. And changing the function did help there. Also, what would be the best way to simultaneously rename and copy files elsewhere? I'm a bit stuck at taking the relative path name of the file and changing it before copying it.
